# Need help using Taylor series expansion to evaluate a limit

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm currently stuck on a problem and would appreciate any help or guidance that you can provide. The problem asks to use Taylor series expansion to evaluate the following limit:

$$​\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{\ln x-\left( x-1\right)  }{\left( x-1\right)^{2}  }$$

Here's what I've tried so far:

I started by finding the first few derivatives of $f(x) = \ln x$ evaluated at $x=1$:

$$f(1) = \ln 1 = 0$$

$$f'(1) = \frac{d}{dx} \ln x \bigg|_{x=1} = 1$$

$$f''(1) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \ln x \bigg|_{x=1} = -1$$

$$f'''(1) = \frac{d^3}{dx^3} \ln x \bigg|_{x=1} = 2!(-1) = 2$$

Using the Taylor series expansion for $f(x) = \ln x$ about $x = 1$, we get:

$$\ln x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(x-1)^n = 0 + 1(x-1)^1 - \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 - \frac{1}{3!}(x-1)^3 + \cdots$$

Next, I tried to apply this series to the given limit by replacing $\ln x$ with the series and simplifying:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{\ln x-(x-1)}{(x-1)^{2}} &= \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{\left[1(x-1)-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 - \frac{1}{3!}(x-1)^3 + \cdots\right]-(x-1)}{(x-1)^2} &= \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{-\frac{1}{2}(x-1) - \frac{1}{3!}(x-1)^2 + \cdots}{(x-1)} &= \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3!}(x-1) + \cdots}{1} &= -\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
However, I'm not sure if my approach is correct or if there's a simpler way to solve this problem using Taylor series expansion. Any feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks fine. But I suspect that you were expected to know that, near $1$,$$\log x=(x-1)-\frac12(x-1)^2+\frac13(x-1)^3+\cdots$$instead of actually computing that Taylor series.

Comment: $f'''(1)$ is not equal to $-2$ but to $2.$ And the term of order $3$ in $\ln x$ is not $- \frac{1}{3!}(x-1)^3$ but $+\frac2{3!}(x-1)^3.$ And you don't need it anyway: stop at the order $2$ and write explicitely the rest: no dots, but $o((x-1)^2).$

Comment: @AnneBauval You're absolutely right, the third derivative of $\ln x$ evaluated at $x=1$ is indeed $f'''(1) = \frac{d^3}{dx^3} \ln x \bigg|_{x=1} = 2$, and the term of order 3 in $\ln x$ is $+\frac{2}{3!}(x-1)^3$.

With these corrections, the Taylor series expansion for $\ln x$ about $x=1$ becomes:

$$\ln x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(x-1)^n = 0 + 1(x-1)^1 - \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 + \frac{2}{3!}(x-1)^3 + \mathcal{O}((x-1)^4)$$

Comment: And applying this series to the given limit, we get:

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{\ln x-(x-1)}{(x-1)^{2}} &= \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{\left[1(x-1)-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 + \frac{2}{3!}(x-1)^3 + \mathcal{O}((x-1)^4)\right]-(x-1)}{(x-1)^2} &= \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{-\frac{1}{2}(x-1) + \frac{2}{3!}(x-1)^2 + \mathcal{O}((x-1)^3)}{(x-1)^2} &= \\ 
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3!}(x-1) + \mathcal{O}((x-1)^2)}{(x-1)} &= \\
-\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}$$
Thank you again for catching those mistakes and providing helpful feedback!